# block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent

Tags: disk, kvm-virtualization, ext4, fsck

#### The error :

```
[Sun Sep  6 11:15:56 2015] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757: group 113, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 34 vs 33 free clusters
[Sun Sep  6 11:15:56 2015] Aborting journal on device dm-0-8.
[Sun Sep  6 11:15:56 2015] EXT4-fs (dm-0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[Sun Sep  6 11:15:56 2015] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_free_blocks:4901: Journal has aborted
```

#### The setup :

Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS 64-bit.
Running under Virtual Machine Manager 0.9.5.
VM disk :

> 20GB
>   Disk bus : Virtio
>   Storage Format : raw
>   Cache mode : Default
>   IO mode : Default

I tried rebooting and fsck ran, and I chose "f" for fix, but ~45 minutes later the same thing happened.

What gives ?